# ¿Como imprimir todas correctamente una funcion html javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Por algún motivo no soy capaz de sacar correctamente las posiciones de este array**[4,0,3,4,8,5,3,1,4,8,4,3,2,6,1,8,9,7,8,5,0,1,5]**, en este caso quiero que se marquen las posiciones en las que esta el 5, lo he conseguido sacar y ahora quiero que aparezca cada vez que alguien pulsa un botón pero no se cómo hacerlo ya que solo me saca un -1, aquí el código que tengo:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var numeros = [4,0,3,4,8,5,3,1,4,8,4,3,2,6,1,8,9,7,8,5,0,1,5];
    var salida = 0;
    while(salida > -1){
        salida = numeros.indexOf(5, salida);
        if (salida > -1) { // si encuentra otra ocurrencia la muestra.
            console.log('posición: '+salida);
            salida++; // se incrementa para buscar desde la posición siguiente
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = salida ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/mensaje.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Ejercicio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Calcular la posicion del 5</button>
    
        <p id="demo"></p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Te recomendaría que cuides un poco el lenguaje, no estamos en el patio de un colegio. Intenta ser un poco más profesional y usar alguna que otra palabra malsonante menos.

Comment: Tienes razon, disculpa es mi fustracion ante mi ineptitud

Comment: No saber hacer algo, no es ineptitud. Programar no es algo que se asemeje a cualquier otra cosa que hacemos naturalmente, es algo que se debe aprender. Por supuesto hay gente a la que se le da mejor y gente a la que se le da peor, pero nadie nace aprendido. Como todo, sea hobby o trabajo, es cuestión de dedicación y estudio. Con el tiempo, lo que hoy no te sale, te resultará fácil y lo harás sin pensar, y por supuesto, habrá otras cosas que tampoco te saldrán, siempre las habrá. Los programadores nunca dejamos de aprender, porque las tecnologías no dejan de cambiar y evolucionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te fijas, en la consola te aparecen correctamente las posiciones de los 5, entonces por qué no se imprimen? Bueno pues... porque los intentas imprimir en la página solo tras salir del bucle, y solo sale del bucle cuando ya no hay más ocurrencias del número 5! (es decir, cuando el `indexOf(5)` es -1, que es lo que te imprime). Te dejo aquí la versión arreglada, si es que he entendido bien lo que intentas:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var numeros = [4,0,3,4,8,5,3,1,4,8,4,3,2,6,1,8,9,7,8,5,0,1,5];
    var salida = 0;
    while(salida > -1){
        salida = numeros.indexOf(5, salida);
        if (salida > -1) { // si encuentra otra ocurrencia la muestra.
            console.log('posición: '+salida);
            /* Moviendo esta línea aquí adentro, antes de incrementar la posición, 
            podemos simplemente "concatenar" el anterior valor del elemento demo con 
            la nueva posición encontrada, añadiendo un espacio para separar las posiciones*/
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + salida + " ";
            salida++; // se incrementa para buscar desde la posición siguiente
        }
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/mensaje.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Ejercicio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Calcular la posicion del 5</button>
    
        <p id="demo"></p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

He añadido un comentario explicando los cambios que hice al código, cualquier cosa no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Si era eso muchas gracias